# Why does node mailer fail to send emails on a private host while it works good on localhost and render

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel, nodemailer, shared-hosting

I am facing a problem sending emails to my clients by nodemailer. I am using a shared hosting with a cpanel. It does not send emails from it while it sends from other hosts.

Here is the function that sends emails in my code.

```js
const transporter = mailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL,
    pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS,
  },
});

app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
  const data = {
    name: req.body.name,
    mail: req.body.mail,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    msg: req.body.msg,
    title: "new message form contact section",
  };

  if (data.phone.length == 0) {
    data["phone"] = "not given!";
  }

  ejs.renderFile("./views/mail.ejs", data, function (err, ejsout) {
    transporter.sendMail({
      from: process.env.MAIL,
      to: "***********@gmail.com",
      subject: "Support request ‍♂️",
      html: ejsout,
    });
    res.render("msg", { msg: "Message was send successfully!" });
  });
});
```

Also, I have checked if my app could access the .env file and read it. And it works probably. I tried to restart the application and the problem is still.

Should I use another node js library?

**edit**
I had updated my code to that and It gives me the error message while using Render hosting it sends me it is successful.

```js
ejs.renderFile("./views/mail.ejs", data, async function (err, ejsout) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      transporter.sendMail(
        {
          from: process.env.MAIL,
          to: "*********@gmail.com",
          subject: "Support request ‍♂️",
          html: ejsout,
        },
        (err, info) => {
          if (err) {
            res.render("msg", {
              msg: "Error there is a problem sending your message! Please Contact us via Email.",
            });
          } else {
            res.render("msg", { msg: "Message was send successfully!" });
          }
        }
      );
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Gmail instead use your host Email address.

You can get your email address settings easily in the cPanel by navigating your email and then use email, password, SMTP, host.